# Cannot remove files from sdcard using delete functions

Tags: android, file-io, sd-card

In my application I save a table as an image. User can delete a file (image) once he's opened in. I'm using the following code to open an image when user clicks on "Open":

```
File directory=new  File(extStorageDirectory,File.separator+"myDirectory"+File.separator);
File fileInDirectory=new File(directory, fileName); 

//I save the opened file's path n "filePath"
filePath=fileInDirectory.getAbsolutePath();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileInDirectory.getAbsolutePath());  
ImageView ivv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
ivv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

//I enable the delete button
deleteFile.setEnabled(true);
```

File is opened without any problem. And when the user clicks on "Delete" I do the following:

```
  //I create a file using the filePath I saved earlier
  File file=new File(filePath);
  file.delete();
```

But it doesn't remove the file from sdcard. I've verified and the filePath is correct. I've also tried deleteFile(String) function:

```
 deleteFile(fileNeme);
 //fileName is the name of my file that I save earlier and I've verified it by printing it and there is no problem.
```

I've put

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in my manifest file. So I don't think it's a problem of rights, as I'm able to write and  read from sdcard.

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:
Here's my code to save the file.

```
this.save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(LensCalculator.this);
alert.setTitle("Save");
alert.setMessage("Enter file name");

final EditText input=new EditText(MyActivity.this);
alert.setView(input);

alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TableView table=(TableView) findViewById(R.id.tableId);
    table.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap b=table.getDrawingCache();
    Canvas canvas=new Canvas(b);
    canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0f, 175f, null);
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    String fileName=input.getText().toString();
    File directory =new File(extStorageDirectory+File.separator+"myDirectory"+File.separator);
    if(!directory.mkdir())
           directory.mkdir();
    File file = new File(directory, fileName);
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
        FileOutputStream fOut=openFileOutput("public.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE|Context.MODE_APPEND);
        OutputStreamWriter osw=new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        osw.write(fileName+"\n");

        osw.close();
        fOut.close();
        outStream.close();
        table.destroyDrawingCache();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Check the return value of `deleteFile()` --- it'll tell you whether it worked or not. In addition, make sure that the file's not open anywhere when you delete it; that might cause the deletion to fail.

Comment: also there is a deleteOnExit that may be less strict and allow scheduling for deletion a file that is opened

Comment: @DavidGiven I've checked the deleteFile value and it's "false". I close all the "streams" after opening the file. So I don't see how can i check if my file is open some where :s.

Comment: @njzk2 No, on Android this won't work. It says in documentation that "on Android, the application lifecycle does not include VM termination, so calling this method will not ensure that files are deleted."

Comment: @njzk2 tried using deleteOnExit() but doesn't work in my case. May be i'm using it wrong. I added it after I've opened my file. Didn't work so I tried adding it in delete function but no effect.

Comment: @Anila Are you sure `file.delete();` this line is executed at all? It should work if the path is correct & you have the permission & file is not open.

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS well I think if it's returning "true" it is executed unless I'm wrong about it.

Comment: `File.delete()` returning false means failure. Unfortunately I haven't figured out how to get Android to tell me what the errno is, so I can't suggest any way to find out *why* it failed...

Comment: Feel free to upvote and and all comments you thought were useful!

Answer (score 0):

Just try: `yourFile.delete();`

Comment: I've already tried it. The return value is true but the file stays in sdcard.

Comment: @appserv and what is he trying ?

Comment: Did you close all strems? Check it.

Comment: @appserv just double checked, i'm closing all the streams.

Answer (score 0):

If the path is correct & you have the permission & file is not open then it should work. This is a mysterious situation. Do you get any exceptions? Make sure you don't have something like this:

```
catch(Exception e) { 
 // Do nothing
}
```

And this one is a remote possibility but anyways. How do you check the file is deleted? Remember that when you connect the phone to your computer and when the SD card is mounted your app won't be able to access it(so won't be able to delete the file).

Another remote possibility... Try to add:

```
/*...*/
ivv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
bitmap.recycle();
bitmap = null;
```

**EDIT**

I don't understand why do you need such a complex code, this could be much simpler:

```
File file = new File(directory, fileName);
try {
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
    FileOutputStream fOut=openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE|Context.MODE_APPEND);
    OutputStreamWriter osw=new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
    osw.write(fileName+"\n");

    osw.close();
    fOut.close();
    outStream.close();
    table.destroyDrawingCache();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Like this:

```
FileOutputStream out = null;
try {
       out = new FileOutputStream(directory + fileName);
       bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
       try {
           if(out != null) {
               out.close();
           }
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

Comment: ok so I don't have Catch (exeception e){}. I've tried bitmap.recycle.. and the app crashes raising NullPointerException. I'm testing my app on my phone so to check if it's deleted i open the directory where i save my files. So this can be the problem?

Comment: Why do you get nullpointer exception? bitmap should not be null at that point. Yes, that can be a problem if you forget to turn off "usb storage" mode off after you check.

Comment: Actually I added it in delete function like:
    Bitmap bp=ivv.getDrawingCache();
    bp.recycle();
    bp=null;
Is there somthing wrong with what I'm doing?
usb storage mode is off.

Comment: Remove it from there and add it under `setImageBitmap`. Let's hope this works. If not I don't know what is wrong :(

Comment: Doesn't work instead app crashes giving the following error "Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap ..". :( nothing seems to be working